# 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY' in NODE JS While Calling the third party API (https://)

Tags: node.js, api, express, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

I am trying to call third party HTTP API from my node express app, but am getting the error:

````
       at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1055:34)
       at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
       at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:633:8) code: 'UNABLE_TO_GET_ISSUER_CERT_LOCALLY' ```
````

node: "8.9.3"

windows 10

I have tried

1. generated the certificate from openssl
2. `npm config set strict-ssl true`
3. `npm config -g set cafile C:\Users\youruser\.certificates\yourcertname.crt`

I don't know what I am missing

Comment: Can you share the code where you are making the call to the third party api? What module are you using for making the API call? `àxios` or `fetch` or something else?

Comment: Thanks , Issue was fixed .  I forget to add the application name in host file for openssl validation.